# Convert Spring bean configuration into XML configuration

Tags: spring

i am working on BIRT reporting tool. which is need to called by spring MVC.
i got one example from spring which is [here](http://www.springsource.org/BusinessIntelligenceWithSpringAndBIRT). in this example, configuration is done via bean. can anyone help me convert this configuration in to xml based configuration ?

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "org.eclipse.birt.spring.core","org.eclipse.birt.spring.example" })
@Configuration

public class BirtWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/reports").setViewName("birtView");
    }

    @Bean
    public BirtView birtView() {
        BirtView bv = new BirtView();
        // bv.setReportFormatRequestParameter("ReportFormat");
        // bv.setReportNameRequestParameter("ReportName");
        bv.setBirtEngine(this.engine().getObject());
        return bv;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanNameViewResolver beanNameResolver() {
        BeanNameViewResolver br = new BeanNameViewResolver();
        return br;
    }

    @Bean
    protected BirtEngineFactory engine() {
        BirtEngineFactory factory = new BirtEngineFactory();
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I wants a similar configuration in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no tool for extracting Spring annotations to Spring bean context xml file. You'll have to do it by hand, shouldn't be too hard as all the Spring annotations functionality can be duplicated into Spring context xml tags.

Comment: i can create that 3 beans in xml. but what about addViewControllers method. how to configure that in xml ?

Comment: It's true, some things have different semanthics in Spring Annotations than in Spring xml. It is however possible, look at Spring MVC docs to see how to configure controllers and view resolvers in XML:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Comment: i an not able to find anything useful form this link.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use spingmvc, so no need the configuration files.

my solution is that in Birt Script i call the impl java file like this :

```
sampleService = new Packages.com.example.warlock.service.SampleServiceImpl();
pojo = new Packages.com.example.warlock.entity.Sample();
iterator = sampleService.getSamples().iterator();
```

because my SampleService is a interface and SampleServiceImpl is impl java, the two java file are not config as @Bean.

At first i want to get the data from ModelMap but failed, so i skip the controller and straight to call Service, then final call the DAO to get the Data from DB